# Select language in grails

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, internationalization, selector

I want to create a link that allows me to choose the language, either Spanish or English.

```
 <g: link controller = "$ {params.controller}" action = "$ {params.action}" params = "$ {params + [lang: 'en']}"> Inglés </ g: link>
 <g: link controller = "$ {params.controller}" action = "$ {params.action}" params = "$ {params + [lang: 'en']}"> Spanish </ g: link>
```

With this code I could select the language but if I change my view reselect the default language, not the language that I just choose.

How could I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by change my view? Do this mean that you go to some other page or just refresh?

Comment: What's that params.controller and params.action? What action and controller you are trying to hit?

Comment: This should be pretty easy. Did you try any ui plugin like twitterbootstrap one? It has a sample localisation support. That should help you!

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Yes, if i go to some other page

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I just copy the code of a page and it works but only for the current page

Answer (score 0):

You can store the lang parameter in session and update params.lang in filters, this way you can set the language preference of the user for whole session.